# Is there a way to change the Data Type of PasswordHash from String to Byte array in Asp.Net Core Identity

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am implementing the asp.net core identity library in the minimal API project, and the user table's PasswordHash field performs its default hashing and salt but I want to perform my custom hashing and salting password.
So, how can I change the type of PasswordHash from "string" to "byte[]"

[image]

Also, the PasswordHash field should not implement any default hashing mechanism

Comment: No, because this is an implementation from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.

Comment: Why do you want change that type?

Comment: You can replace the `IPasswordHasher` implementation with your own. I'm not sure I would advise this course of action unless you're doing it to integrate with a separate service.

Comment: @kanils_ I want to do this because I want to use HMACSHA512 Password hashing and salt mechanism with byte[] data type.

Comment: Couldn't you just represent the hashed `byte[]` as a `string`? It would be much less of a headache than the alternative.

Comment: @Llama I can check `IPasswordHasher`, if it works I don't mind the type whether it's in byte or string. I just want the hmacsha512 mechanism to implement at its full.

Comment: Just use `Convert.ToBase64String` and `Convert.FromBase64String` to store the string val in the database. You can then create whatever byte[] you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this

on registration

```
 private void CreatePasswordHash(string Password, out byte[] PasswordHash, out byte[] PasswordSalt)
    {
        using (var hmac = new HMACSHA512())
        {
            PasswordSalt = hmac.Key;
            PasswordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Password));
        }
    }
```

Then,

```
 public async Task<ServiceResponse<AspNetUsers>> AddUser(AddUserDto user)
    {
        var ServiceResponse = new ServiceResponse<AspNetUsers>();
        AspNetUsers Users = _mapper.Map<AspNetUsers>(user);
        try
        {
            if (await UserExist(Users.UserName))
            {
                ServiceResponse.Success = false;
                ServiceResponse.Message = "User Already Exist";
                return ServiceResponse;
            }
            CreatePasswordHash(Users.PasswordHash, out byte[] PasswordMade, out byte[] PasswordSalt);

            Users.Id = CommonCode.NewGUID();
            Users.SecurityStamp = CommonCode.NewGUID();
            Users.ConcurrencyStamp = CommonCode.NewGUID();
            Users.PasswordHash = Convert.ToBase64String(PasswordMade);
            Users.PasswordSalt = PasswordSalt;
            var AddUser = await _context.Users.AddAsync(Users);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            ServiceResponse.Data = await _context.Users.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == Users.Id);
            ServiceResponse.Success = true;
            ServiceResponse.Message = "User successfully added!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ServiceResponse.Success = false;
            ServiceResponse.Message = ex.Message;
        }
        return ServiceResponse;
    }
```

at the time of login, I did something like this.

```
        private bool VerifyPasswordHash(string password, byte[] passwordHash, byte[] passwordSalt)
    {
        using (var hmac = new HMACSHA512(passwordSalt))
        {
            var computeHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            for (int i = 0; i < computeHash.Length; i++)
            {
                if (computeHash[i] != passwordHash[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

then,

```
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<string>> Login(LoginInformation Credentials)
        {
        var ServiceResponse = new ServiceResponse<string>();
        try
        {
            var User = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Email.ToLower() == Credentials.Email.ToLower());
                            
            if(User == null){
            ServiceResponse.Success = false;
            ServiceResponse.Message = "User not found.";
            }
            else
            if(!VerifyPasswordHash(Credentials.Password, Convert.FromBase64String(User.PasswordHash), User.PasswordSalt))
            {
                ServiceResponse.Success = false;
                ServiceResponse.Message = "Username Or Password Is Incorrect";
            }
            else{
                ServiceResponse.Data = "Login success"; 
                ServiceResponse.Success = true;
                ServiceResponse.Message = "Login is Successfull!";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ServiceResponse.Data = string.Empty;
            ServiceResponse.Success = false;
            ServiceResponse.Message = ex.Message;
        }
        return ServiceResponse;
    }
```